# ASP.NET MVC RedirectToAction won't redirect me to new ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an application that you can create a user with a name and email. When the user is created, they are added to the database and they are assigned an ID (primary key).

When I create a user, the function RedirectToAction won't redirect me to the new user's homepage but still redirects me to the user that had created the user although I'm telling the controller to redirect me to the newly created ID's user homepage.

```
    return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID })
```

The user account is being created as I can see it in the database and a list of users so the AddUser function works, it just seems to be this line of code that is not working.

I am initializing the application into the first ID (1) user's profile that can then create another user.

Can someone tell me what has gone wrong here?

Routeconfig.cs file to point to the first users ID as initialisation:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "User",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "GetUser", ID = 1 }
            );
```

Controller that adds user:

```
            public ActionResult AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                userService.AddUser(userAdd);
                return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID });
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

My user DAO and IDAO are following.

DAO :

```
    public void AddUser(User user, TheContext context)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

IDAO:

```
    void AddUser(User user, TheContext context);
```

My user service layer code is:

Service:

```
    public void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
    {
        User newUser = new User()
        {
            Name = userAdd.Name,
            Email = userAdd.Email
        };

        using (var context = new TheContext())
        {
            userDAO.AddUser(newUser, context);
        }
    }
```

IService:

```
     void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd);
```

**GetUser action**:
DAO:

```
public User GetUser(int id, TheContext context)
    {
        context.Users.Include(h => h.UserDetails).ToList();
        return context.Users.Find(id);
    }
```

IDAO:

```
 User GetUser(int id, TheContext context);
```

Service:

```
        public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new TheContext())
        {
            return userDAO.GetUser(id, context);
        }
    }
```

IService:

```
User GetUser(int id);
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        return View(userService.GetUser(id));
    }
```

GetUser.cshtml view:

```
    @model Tester.Data.Models.Domain.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetUser";
}

<h2>My Test App</h2>

<div>
    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "AddUser", "User")</p>

</div>
    <h2>Details for @Model.Name</h2>
@if (Model.UserDetails.Count != 0)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/User/GetUserDetails.cshtml", Model.UserDetails);
}
```

Initaliser class:

```
protected override void Seed(TheContext context)
{
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.ID = "1";
    user1.Name = "test";
    user1.Email = "test@test.com";
    context.Users.Add(user1);

    UserDetail userDetail1 = new UserDetail();
    userDetail1.Name = "test";
    userDetail1.Email = "test.com";
    context.UserDetails.Add(userDetail1);

    context.SaveChanges();
```

I could however use:

```
TheContext.Data.Models.Domain.User user = new TheContext.Data.Models.Domain.User();
user.Name = "test";
user.Email = "test@test.com";

TheContext.Data.Models.Domain.UserDetail userDetail = new TheContext.Data.Models.Domain.UserDetail();
userDetail.Name = "test";
userDetail.Email = "test@test.com";
```

T-SQL for Users:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [ID]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

T-SQL for UserDetails:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserDetails] (
    [ID]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [User_ID]       INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserDetails_dbo.Users_User_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([User_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([ID])
);
```

User class:

```
    public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
}
```

UserDetails class:

```
public class UserDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do you know if in return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID }) line, your userAdd.ID has valid value? It was never assigned as i can see. You only assigned values from it to the properties of another instance. Try returning Id from void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd); in IService and use that in your controller. RedirectToAction code looks good to me.

Comment: @Dave i'm not certain, is there a way to check if it is assigned a value? As for IService & Service, I have implemented void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd, int ID). For the controller I have edited the actionresult to (UserAdd userAdd, int ID) and I'm returning the value ID (userService.AddUser(userAdd, ID)). Those edits haven't worked unfortuately so I have a feeling you're correct with the ID not being assigned a value. Could you explain further please? I have looked into the database and the user I create is assigned an ID value there as it's the primary key in the table.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on `return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = userAdd.ID })` call and see if after adding a user, `userAdd.ID` has a new ID value. If it doesn't have a value there, you need to update your `IService.void AddUser(UserAdd userAdd);` to return `int/string` instead of `void`. Declare a variable in that method, after the user is created, assign that variable from `newUser`  instance and return it to the controller. Than in `RedirectToAction` call, use the returned value as an id. I cannot format code here, so unfortunately i cannot post it here.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for telling me. So I can see that the userAdd.ID assigned is 1 which is why it is taking me beack to ID 1's page. Do you know why it is assigned it as 1 when I have ID as the primary key and because when I look into the database, the ID value 2 is assigned.

Comment: may be when you are logged in with user ID 1, it is being passed and saved into the viewmodel. so when you post request, ID 1 saved in that viewmodel also gets passed back to the controller which was never updated later on. As i suggested earlier, from your service return a new ID and use that instead.

Comment: i added an answer with my suggestion. let me know if have any doubts. for some reason, i cannot mention your name after @ .

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using an `ID` from posted view model, get `ID` of newly created record from service and use it.

**IService:**
`int AddUser(UserAdd userAdd);`

**Service:**

```
public int AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
{
   var userId = 0;
   User newUser = new User()
   {
       Name = userAdd.Name,
       Email = userAdd.Email
   };

   using (var context = new TheContext())
   {
       userDAO.AddUser(newUser, context);
       // assing Id here after add
       userId = newUser.ID;
   }
   return userId;
}
```

**Action method:**

```
public ActionResult AddUser(UserAdd userAdd)
{
   try
   {
     // capture Id from service
     var newId = userService.AddUser(userAdd);
     return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = newId });
   }
   catch
   {
     return View(userAdd);   // return view with posted model so you don't loose data
   }
}
```

Comment: @Sergey i read your answer. that doesn't solve the problem. In your suggested call `return GetUser(userAdd.ID )` Id is always 1, so OP is seeing the same page again. Based on what OP described, RedirectToAction() is not an issue. You just wrote the same thing in different way. Here we need to get an updated Id for newly added record.

Comment: your string AddUser(UserAdd userAdd) return string, but Id should be int. And all your AddUser code doesn't do anything new, only adds an error. And it is an error to use redirect instead of just calling action.

Comment: @Sergey i posted an answer when i was unaware about the datatype, so there is comment in code: `// assuming primary key is of type string`
I don't see any difference in the result with following when Id is 1.
`return GetUser(userAdd.ID)`
`return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id = newId });`

They both ultimately fetches the same user from the database. How did it fix the issue? 
If you read the second paragraph in question, problem is not that the redirect is not working at all. It is redirecting to the same user again. OP needs to redirect to the new user.

Comment: I have just changed my primary key datatype to string, it was originally int id but is now string id. I have used your code and I am getting the error in UserService: "'UserService.AddUser(UserAdd)': not all code paths return a value". If it helps, I am using a class to initalise the first user and some details, i have 2 options, could you suggest which would be more appropriate or if they are essentially the same. I have editied the post with the details

Comment: @DAVID sorry, it was a typo. method should return userId at the end. updated my answer. You don't need to change the datatype of PK. If you did, make sure AddUser() method in service returns the same datatype.

Comment: @Dave thank you so much it is now working! Just thought i'd ask as it may be a quick fix. When I initialise the database, my userDetails dont match up with the User because the field User_ID is null in the UserDetail table. I cannot assign it during the initialisation either as User_ID is a field created by the database as a foreign key for Users. I have to manually enter 1 into the User_ID field for the data to be listed on the users homepage. Can you have a look please and see if there is anything I have missed? I have edited the post again

Comment: @DAVID glad its working now. don't forget to mark the answer. 
for seeding initial data, i updated my answer. i currently do not have a way to verify that, but that should work. give it a try and let me know.

Comment: I have done, won't show up as an upvote as I don't have 15 rep but it's nice to be welcomed by some awesome people. I had tried it but no luck unfortunately, error - System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' on line user1.UserDetails.Add(userDetail1); . States that   user1.UserDetails is null

Comment: @DAVID that's because it would not have been assigned in your User class. As a best practice, in the constructor of User class, assign navigation property as:
`UserDetails = new HashSet<UserDetail>();`

Or initialize it when you seed data using my example similar to what you have done with local UserDetail object.

something like: `user1.UserDetails = new List<UserDetail>();`